# Different options for migrating

Tags: migration

Can someone suggest me different methods of migration from 2010 to 2016 directly(without going into 2013)?

I know some third party tools like ShareGate,Metalogix etc but they are not working in our env. Our SharePoint 2010 fabric has lot of integrated stuffs like BI,reporting servers, nintex etc

Answer (score 3):

Without using the 3rd party tools there is no direct way to migrate from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016. So it is up to one's requirement which option they use.

- Use 3rd party tools but not every thing will be migrated using this option like customization / solutions will have to re write.
- build a SharePoint 2013 farm and use content database upgrade approach. Again this option will required a lot of work.

but there is no other supported method.

Comment: when we attach a database to 2013 env, do we need to install all the components or just SharePoint installation is enough for upgrade? and then install all components on 2016